# Linq to Sharepoint results in invalid cast

Tags: linq, list, sharepoint, distinct

I am programming a Silverlight application in c#, which takes lists from a sharepoint.
I want the distinct elements from a specific column in the list.
After getting the query I can't handle with the var-datatype. The program exists everytime, when I want to make a datacast, for example in an ListItemCollection.

Here is the code:

```
ListItemCollection bla;

var result = bla.Select(m => m["Region"]).Distinct();

ListItemCollection a = (ListItemCollection)result; //Error happens here
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ deals with instances of IEnumerable<> or IQueryable<>. `Distinct` returns an IEnumerable<> or IQueryable<> depending on the type of the original collection. In your case, it returns an IQueryable

You are trying to cast that IQueryable  to a ListItemCollection, which understandably results in an invalid cast exception.

You don't need to do something else to start working with the items. You can iterate over them with `foreach`, convert them to an array or list with `ToArray()` and `ToList()` etc

Answer (score 1):

Linq provider for SharePoint does not support `Distinct` operator which is why this error occurs.

According to MSDN:

> Some LINQ queries cannot be completely translated into CAML. However,
>   however such queries can, in principle, run correctly because they can
>   be executed in two stages. First, the LINQ to SharePoint provider
>   translates as much of the query into CAML as it can and executes that
>   query

Please refer [Unsupported LINQ Queries and Two-stage Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536585%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for a more details.

### Two stage approach

To correct this error, you should cut your queries in two stages to force the first query execution before the second one. To do that, you should for example transform the first `IEnumerable<T>` in a list thanks to `ToList()` method.

The following example demonstrates how to return unique values from `ListItemCollection` object:

```
var result = items.ToList().Select(i => i["Region"].ToString()).Distinct(); //System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctIterator<string> type
foreach (var item in result)
{
      //...
}
```